# VS Code wrong Auto Suggestion with PHP Intelphense v.1.8.2

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I have the following problem.

In VSCode, i am using PHP Intelphense v. 1.8.2

When adding an img tag within a .php file (html area) i got tons of suggestions in the src attribut, what is wrong.
Within the src attribute i only want to see folders.

Example php Wrong behaviour:
[image]

Expected behaviour:
[image]

How can i make correct folder suggestions only, in an img src attribute? (showing/suggestion folders only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following solution. Looks like,there are other Standard Basic PHP Settings beside the PHP-intelephense extension.

In settings.json I added:

```
      "php.suggest.basic": false,
      "php.validate.enable": false,
```

After that the extension PHP-Intelephense works like charm again.